# Apply indexing multiple times on numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array A of size N and another array B with permutation indices of the array A.
Now I would like to apply this permutation multiple times to the array A. Is there a nice and efficient numpy command for that?

As an example for reproducibility:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(121421)

# Example Array
A = np.random.uniform(0, 100, (100, 3))

# Permutation indices
B = np.random.choice(np.arange(A.shape[0]), A.shape[0], replace=False)

# Permute many times
npermut = 10000
C = np.array(B)
for n in range(npermut-1):
    C = C[B]
print(A[C])
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably provide a smaller example for clarity

Comment: Thank you, I reduced the size of the array A to 100.

Comment: `np.random.shuffle(C)`? But I don't understand why you need to do that 10000 times?

Comment: Unfortunately it would not work. I need to apply the indexing B many times, as at each step, the array A is reordered with B. After 10000 steps, the array A will have changed so that the indexing B has been applied 10000 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any numpy function that directly solves this problem. However, you can vastly improve the performance by analyzing the problem mathematically. What you're doing is computing the n-th power of a permutation s. Suppose n = 2^m, then

`s^n = (((s^2)^2)...)^2`

where there are m terms in the parentheses, and so we reduced the number of indexing operations down to O(log(n)). If n is not a power of 2, then we write

`n = a_1*2^1 + a_2*2^2 + ... + a_m*2^m`

where m is the largest integer such that 2^m < n. The sequence (a_1, ..., a_m) is just the binary representation of n in reverse. Then

`s^n = g_m(s^(2^m))...g_1(s^(2^1))`

where g_m(x) = x if a_m = 1 else g_m(x) = 1. There are at most m+(m-1)+...+1 = m*(m+1)/2 indexing operations, i.e. the number of indexing operations scales as O(m^2) = O(2log(n)) = O(log(n)).

The following code illustrates the above idea:

```
def _perm_power_exp(perm, M):
    """
    Computes perm^(2^M) = ((perm^2)^2)...^2
    """
    for _ in range(M):
        perm = perm[perm]
    return perm

def perm_power(perm, N):
    """
    Fast computation of perm^N
    """
    if N == 1:
        return perm
    
    bin_rep = [int(i) for i in str(bin(N))[2:]] # binary representation of N
    
    perms = []
    for i, j in enumerate(reversed(bin_rep)):
        # j corresponds to a_{i+1} in the above explanation
        if j == 1:
            perms.append(_perm_power_exp(perm, i))
    
    perm = perms[0]
    for perm_i in perms[1:]:
        perm = perm_i[perm]
    
    return perm
```

To check correctness and also test the speed improvement, I'll also define the function

```
def perm_power_naive(perm, N):
    new_perm = perm.copy()
    for _ in range(N-1):
        new_perm = new_perm[perm]
    return new_perm
```

Notice that this function is exactly the same as what you're currently doing, so you can just replace that section of your code with the new optimized code.

If I run

```
D, N = 100, 1000
for _ in range(1000):
    B = np.random.choice(D, D, replace=False)
    C1 = perm_power(B, N)
    C2 = perm_power_naive(B, N)
    assert (C1 == C2).all()
```

there is no assertion error raised, thus showing that the optimized code is (likely) working correctly. I've tried other combinations of D and N and the assertion always passes.

I also ran the following code in jupyter notebook to benchmark performance:

```
D, N = 100, 100000
B = np.random.choice(D, D, replace=False)
%timeit perm_power(B, N)
%timeit perm_power_naive(B, N)
```

The result is

```
18.1 µs ± 18 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
21.2 ms ± 310 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

As you see, the performance gain is around 1000x when N = 100000.

Comment: An addition note: I just realized that this is just a special case (and suboptimal implementation) of the 'exponentiation by squaring' or 'fast pow' algorithm, which in general applies to powers of elements of semigroups. Permutations are elements of the symmetric group, so the algorithm applies.